# How to build a Maven POM file for both Android and Java releases

Tags: java, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-profiles

**My requirements**

I have a Java ulitities library. I want to make 2 jar files. One for Android and the another for Java.

For Android jar, I want to exclude JDBC package.

I want to upload both jar files & theirs javadoc, javasources into the Maven remote repository.

so I can use the library as below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

OR Android classifier

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <classifier>android</classifier>
</dependency>
```

**Here is my POM.xml**

```
<project>
    <!-- .... -->

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <name>mylib</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <!-- .... -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- compiler -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- .... -->
            </plugin>

            <!-- jar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- .... -->
            </plugin>

            <!-- source -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- .... -->
            </plugin>

            <!-- javadoc -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- .... -->
            </plugin>

            <!-- nexus-staging-maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- .... -->
            </plugin>

            <!-- maven-gpg -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- .... -->
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <!-- All files - Java -->
        <profile>
            <id>java</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>!android</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>

        <!-- Android - Excluding JDBC, JPA packages -->
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>android</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>

                    <!-- Exclude some packages -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/jdbc/**</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Exclude some packages -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>android</classifier>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/jdbc/**</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Exclude some packages --> 
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/jdbc/**</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Exclude some packages -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourcepath>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourcepath>
                            <sourceFileExcludes>
                                <sourceFileExclude>**/jdbc/**</sourceFileExclude>
                            </sourceFileExcludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- .... -->
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Maven CLI**

1. Run **mvn clean deploy** for deploy Java profile

   **Successfully**. Maven deploy the following files into the remote repository:

   - mylib-1.0.jar
   - mylib-1.0.pom
   - mylib-1.0-javadoc.jar
   - mylib-1.0-sources.jar
   - And all their sign files
2. Run **mvn clean deploy -Dandroid** for deploy Android profile

   The following files are generated:

   - mylib-1.0-android.jar  // append classifier
   - mylib-1.0.pom
   - mylib-1.0-javadoc.jar
   - mylib-1.0-sources.jar
   - And all their sign files

**I got error**

```
    [ERROR] Repository "mycompany-1082" failures
    [ERROR]   Rule "sources-staging" failures
    [ERROR]     * Missing: no main jar artifact found in folder '/com/mycompany/mylib/1.0'
    [ERROR]   Rule "javadoc-staging" failures
    [ERROR]     * Missing: no main jar artifact found in folder '/com/mycompany/mylib/1.0'
```

**Question**: why is this error happening?

Answer (score 1):

The [same issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-5768) has already been reported and it's mainly due to the fact that the main artifact uses a classifier (the `android` one) while sources and javadoc artifact don't, creating a misalignment.

Indeed, the error message is exactly pointing at issues on sources and javadoc artifacts:

```
[ERROR]   Rule "sources-staging" failures
[ERROR]     * Missing: no main jar artifact found in folder '/com/mycompany/mylib/1.0'
[ERROR]   Rule "javadoc-staging" failures
[ERROR]     * Missing: no main jar artifact found in folder '/com/mycompany/mylib/1.0'
```

Saying that the `sources` and the `javadoc` artifact couldn't be found (according to the main artifact classifier): a mismatch.

Luckily, you can fix this issue configuring the `maven-source-plugin` via its [`classifier`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/jar-mojo.html#classifier) option (default to `sources`) and the `maven-javadoc-plugin` via its [`classifier`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/jar-mojo.html#classifier) option (default to `javadoc`).

The `android` profile could actually simply specify the following `property` entries:

```
<properties>
   <maven.source.classifier>android-sources</maven.source.classifier>
   <maven.javadoc.classifier>android-javadoc</maven.javadoc.classifier>
</properties>
```

Indeed using the user properties specified by the aforementioned plugin goals for these options.

To make it even more robust, better to apply the following approach:

```
<properties>
   <android.classifier>android</android.classifier>
   <maven.source.classifier>${android.classifier}-sources</maven.source.classifier>
   <maven.javadoc.classifier>${android.classifier}-javadoc</maven.javadoc.classifier>
</properties>
```

Then use the `${android.classifier}` property for the `classifier` value of the `maven-jar-plugin` also: that is, centralising its value you ensure an easier maintenance.

Comment: Thank you A_Di-Matteo. I will test it next Monday and let you know the result. I voted it.

Comment: @Loc did the sources and javadoc jar get generated with different classifiers?

Comment: Yes. The following files are generated: mylib-1.0-android.jar, mylib-1.0-android-javadoc.jar, mylib-1.0-android-sources.jar, mylib-1.0.pom, and all theirs sign files --- But no luck!

Comment: looking at similar [issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-12704) it should actually work if you upload everything in one shot, having the default artifact, the sources, the javadoc AND the classified artifact deployed together, hence you should not create the classifier as a profiled build, but as part of the default build, as explained [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/attached-jar.html)